# How to set custom ant task classpath?

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath

I wrote a custom task to run in ant that connects to a db, so it requires a jdbc driver. I have packaged this driver/classpath into the jar file, but when I execute in Ant it can't find it??

I have since added a main method, and run this without ant, and it works fine. But still, when I use Ant, it fails to find the driver. I spent lots of time trying things, and finally put the jdbc driver/jar into the jre/lib/ext and it works???

Why can't Ant pickup the driver inside the jar? Is there some limitation to Ant that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with jars within jars. To support this you'll require a special classloader. Far better idea to find a way to better way to manage your classpath. Personally I create executable jars by setting the classpath in my manifest file.

Comment: I'm still confused as to how Ant handles classpath then, I'm having a difficult time understanding why it works by putting the jar in jre/lib/ext, but it fails if I add it to the ant/lib? Shouldn't the classpath that the java task gets come from ant/lib.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I have made the jar executable, but it has no effect on finding the 3rdparty jar. I learned that calling the jar (now that it's executable) from ant, using the java task works. As a temporary solution, I have amended the jar to take in arguments that have, or would otherwise be sent from the task. Does anyone know of an articulate resource to further explain ant classpath hierarchy? It still doesn't make sense to me, why I can't add a driver...but my understanding of ant is still relatively new.